Excel Data Validation with XLOOKUP
Expected result 1: Data validation in D6 with list of unique values from column A - this works
Expected result 2: Data validation in D17 with list of values from column B where column A = D6  - this does not work - only the first value 'red' is shown in D17 data validation drop down - how to change for it to show both red and green?
=XLOOKUP($D6,INDIRECT("TableTest[A]"),INDIRECT("TableTest[B]")) 



I have been using tables along with spill arrays as validation lists. Instead of INDIRECT, I add names in Name Manager, for example, _valid_a = Table1[A] and then for list =_valid_a; similarly =_valid_b# for filtered data.

XLOOKUP() is doing nothing wrong, it is behaving exactly as it needs to be, it will always return the first occurrence of a duplicate lookup value. That said, there are two methods of accomplishing the desired output,
• First Method : Using OFFSET()+XMATCH()+COUNTIF() with INDIRECT() embedded within the functions.


• Formula used in Data Validation for [B]
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("TableTest[B]"),
  XMATCH(D6,INDIRECT("TableTest[A]"))-1,,
  COUNTIF(INDIRECT("TableTest[A]"),D6))


In the above formula we can avoid using INDIRECT() as well, if we don't consider the Structured References thus the formula will be:
=OFFSET($B:$B,XMATCH(D$6,$A:$A)-1,,COUNTIF($A:$A,D$6))


• Second Method : Using helper columns with the FILTER() function and using cell reference with # Spill operator in Data Validation


• Formula used in cell A14 (This can be placed anywhere since its a helper column preferably somewhere hidden)
=FILTER(TableTest[B],TableTest[A]=D6,"")


• Formula used in Data Validation
=A14#


 NOTE: Some caveats here, the first method will always work when the data is sorted by [A], secondly it is highly suggested to avoid using volatile functions like INDIRECT() and OFFSET() since these functions will make Excel work relatively slow, as well as it will keep recalculating whenever there is a change in any open workbook, finally these functions are single threaded. Regarding the second method, one can use it with the helper columns and there shouldn't be any issues arising for the same.


Many thanks Mayukh! I intend to use the validation in another table where the user in column 1 should select a value from TableTest[A] in the data validation drop down and then in column 2 on the same row select a value from TableTest[B] filtered on Tabletest[A] with what was selected in column 1. This works very well with your first method but considering your caveats, do you see a way to adapt your second method to be used in another table? I tried simply putting =FILTER(TableTest[B],TableTest[A]=A2,"")# as data validation source in column 2 but this did not work..

Hi @Fred unfortunately you can't use the FILTER() function in Data Validation directly, because it returns an array, but when you use it as a reference from another helper column it will work. But yes if you are happy in using the first method and think it will help you and you can go ahead to use it.
